# Laravel - How to extract one field for items in a model to an array?

Tags: laravel

I have a table that has a one-to-many relationship with another table.

Call them tables `parent` and `child`

`child` has a field called `field1`

I am trying to get an array of all `field1` values.

In the `parent` Model, I have this function that gets me all children of `parent`

```
 public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
```

Now, in the `parent` model, I also want to get all `field1` values.

I can get all the children like so:

```
$children = $this->children->all();
```

But I just can't figure out how to then index into this to get all the `field1` values.

Maybe it is better to just use  `$this->children` in which case it is a `Collection` and then use some sort of Collection method to extract `field1`?

I tried

```
$this->children->only(['field1'])
```

but that returned nothing, even though field1 certain exists.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pluck method of collecion](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck) to get an array of field1 values:

```
$parent->child->pluck('field1');
```

Or better, you can use [pluck method of query builder (see section Retrieving A List Of Column Values)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results), being even more efficient, with same result:

```
$parent->child()->pluck('field1');
```

Answer (score 1):

`map()` is the function you are looking.

```php
$children = $this->children->all()->map(function($children) {
    return $children->field1;
});
```

A shorter version using Higher Order Message.

```php
$children = $this->children->all()->map->field1;
```